# How to find reflex and convex vertices

Tags: c++, opengl, triangulation

I am trying to implement the ear clipping algorithm based on https://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/TriangulationByEarClipping.pdf but I can't grasp how to find reflex and convex vertices.

The document linked mentiones that a vertex is reflex if its interior angle is > 180. I tried calculating the angle by creating 2 direction vectors (going away from the vertex) and then getting the dot of the two. But this is never above 180 for me.

My background is 3D Art and this is a way for me to learn more about trigonometry. Apologies if I'm missing something very basic!

[image: Here is the polygon in question with the vertex I am struggling with. I keep getting 45 degrees.]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410743/polygon-triangulation-reflex-vertex

Comment: Thanks @AlessandroTeruzzi, the information in that link helped me solved my problem. I had never heard of such a thing as determinate. I have no idea how to mark your link as answer!

Answer (score 1):

The link that @AlessandroTeruzzi posted helpe me solve the issue. No idea how to mark it as the answer. I needed to find the determinate. The link in question: [polygon triangulation reflex vertex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40410743/polygon-triangulation-reflex-vertex)

[This is my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ8Zp.png)

Answer (score -1):

I think to find if vertex is reflex do following :

Given point is A take two adjacent point to A , Lets say B and C. 
Then find vectors (B-A).(C-A) = cos (angle) .
Find inverse cosine of angle in above equation for get the angle . So ,If this cos^-1 (angle) is > 180 then vertex A is reflex.

If you dont know order of vertices 
then how to find Adjacent points to A.
For this you can use some part of Convex Hull Algorithm.

Comment: `1/cos(x)` gives a number in range `[-inf, +inf]`. `acos(x)` (angle x whose cos(x) is given) gives a number in range `[0, +pi]` Your check cos^-1 is wrong in both meanings.

Comment: Sorry I think you got some misunderstanding I tried to wrote mathematical notation for cos inverse. With library functions its defincately acos() and not 1/cos() thanks